# Joomla layout difference edit.php and default.php

Tags: joomla-3.x, view, layout, default

I had already created some custom components  in the past and how it is, at the beginning you cannot understand all things in detail. But with continuing always new question arise.

Could someone explains when to use edit.php in Joomla layout views and when to use default.php instead? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the standard conventions, `edit.php` will be used for the form layout that allows you to edit an item, and `default.php` will be used for viewing an item as well as viewing a list of items.

Typically in Joomla, you will see two types of view folders: singular and plural. The plural version (let's call it "articles"), will just have a `default.php` file that will render a list of articles. The singular version ("article" this time), may have both the `default.php` and `edit.php` or could just have `edit.php`. (Sometimes the default isn't implemented.) If both exist, the `default.php` file would render the article information to be viewed but not edited. The `edit.php` file would render the form allowing you to edit the article.

Comment: Great David. Iam asking this question, because iam facing a problem with my cancel button in my default.php, which is a form with some input fields aswell a save and cancel button. There are some required fields in my form. When i use the cancel button, the form validation informs me to fill out these fields. Could it be a result of using the default.php layout?

Comment: @Perino Nope. That's a separate question though, so open a new question about the cancel button/form validation and I'll pop over there and respond.